# Why MarkForCheck() and setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an issue with the method MarkForCheck() from ChangeDetectorRef. For one usage I had to use `this.cd.markForCheck();` because in console I was getting the values but it was not updating on the view.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}, 50)
```

This resolved my issue.But i guess this is not the right way.Can anyone suggest me how better i can write this?

Comment: It depends the context which who the caller is for this setTimeout? Is it a observable that run outside Angular? Or just a vanilla template function that triggered by some events?